# Implement Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently use the `onKeyDown` event and an `if/else` statement to create keyboard shortcuts:

```
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift && e.Key == Key.Tab) {

} else if (e.Key == Key.Tab) {

} ...
```

However, if I have quite a few more keyboard shortcuts, this gets messy.

Is there a better implementation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should look at implementing [`<CommandBindings>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.commandbindings.aspx) and [`<InputBindings>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings.aspx):

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Settings" CanExecute="SettingsCanExecute" Executed="SettingsExecuted" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="Settings" Key="S" Modifiers="Alt" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Your `<Button>` then becomes:

```
<Button Height="50" Width="50" Margin="50,5,0,0" Command="Settings" />
```

The `SettingsCanExecute` method determines when the button is enabled and the `SettingsExecuted` method is called when the button is pressed or the key combination struck.

You then don't need the `KeyDown` handler.

There's a [full tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands) on Switch On The Code.

More information on [CommandBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx) and [InputBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding.aspx) can be found on the MSDN.

Comment: hmm... when i tried `<CommandBinding Command="Preview" CanExecute ...` i get an error on `Command="Preview"` saying cannot convert "Preview". i am using the RibbonWindow instead of Window. does it make a difference? since RibbonWindow extends Window?

Comment: i am not sure if i missed anything in the tutorial. but looking at the demo code from [John Smith On WPF: Understanding Routed Commands](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/understanding-routed-commands/) i think i need to create a Property on a class then reference it in code... [Snipplr Code Snipplet](http://snipplr.com/view/39602/cwpf-routed-commands/)

Answer (score 2):

Documenting this answer for others, as there is a much simpler way to do this that is rarely referenced, and doesn't require touching the XAML at all.

To link a keyboard shortcut, in the Window constructor simply add a new KeyBinding to the InputBindings collection. As the command, pass in your arbitrary command class that implements ICommand. For the execute method, simply implement whatever logic you need. In my example below, my WindowCommand class takes a delegate that it will execute whenever invoked. When I construct the new WindowCommand to pass in with my binding, I simply indicate in my initializer, the method that I want the WindowCommand to execute.

You can use this pattern to come up with your own quick keyboard shortcuts.

```
public YourWindow() //inside any WPF Window constructor
{
   ...
   //add this one statement to bind a new keyboard command shortcut
   InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding( //add a new key-binding, and pass in your command object instance which contains the Execute method which WPF will execute
      new WindowCommand(this)
      {
         ExecuteDelegate = TogglePause //REPLACE TogglePause with your method delegate
      }, new KeyGesture(Key.P, ModifierKeys.Control)));
   ...
}
```

Create a simple WindowCommand class which takes an execution delegate to fire off any method set on it.

```
public class WindowCommand : ICommand
{
    private MainWindow _window;

    //Set this delegate when you initialize a new object. This is the method the command will execute. You can also change this delegate type if you need to.
    public Action ExecuteDelegate { get; set; }

    //You don't have to add a parameter that takes a constructor. I've just added one in case I need access to the window directly.
    public WindowCommand(MainWindow window)
    {
        _window = window;
    }

    //always called before executing the command, mine just always returns true
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true; //mine always returns true, yours can use a new CanExecute delegate, or add custom logic to this method instead.
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged; //i'm not using this, but it's required by the interface

    //the important method that executes the actual command logic
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (ExecuteDelegate != null) //let's make sure the delegate was set
        {
            ExecuteDelegate();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ExecuteDelegate has not been set. There is no method to execute for this command.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the core ideas behind WPF was to avoid having to touch the code behind. The ideal WPF/MVVM programm has close to 0 lines of code behind.
While it works just fine, it is not good practice.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a reference for that? I've never seen that in print before, but if it's true, that would be good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Every single learning example for MVVM I know of creates a View Model.
Instantiates that View Model in the XAML.
And keeps the Code Behind as barebones as humanly possible.

Everything you have to write in code behind is bound to that specific View by definition. And the arbitrariness of the view is a fundamental concept in MVVM.

Also my math teacher used to say "Mathematicians are lazy writers - the more they write, the more they can make mistakes". I apply that to programming fully.