# How can I handle a customizable hotkey setting?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to let my app's users an option to set a keyboard hotkey for for some feature.

Right now I'm using a `TextBox` with the `KeyDown` event as follows:

```
Key Hotkey;
private void SetHotKey(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).Text = e.Key.ToString();
    Hotkey = e.Key;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The problem with this approach is I can't set complex shortcuts, like [Ctrl]+[F4]. Is there some 3rd-party control that helps with that? Or a better-suited event to subscribe to on a textbox?

***UPDATE:*** I've changed my code but it seems I'm still doing something wrong.

```
Key Hotkey;
bool lControl = false;
bool lAlt = false;
bool lShift = false;
private void SetHotKey(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var k = e.Key;
    if (e.IsDown)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        tb.Text = "";
        lControl = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl);
        lAlt = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt);
        lShift = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift);
        if (lControl) tb.Text += "Ctrl+";
        if (lAlt) tb.Text += "Alt+";
        if (lShift) tb.Text += "Shift+";
        tb.Text = e.Key.ToString();
        Hotkey = e.Key;
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

How can I make it work and look cleaner as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#/WPF: Implement Keyboard Shortcuts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574405/c-wpf-implement-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: @Eldho not exactly. I'm asking about something different.

Comment: The above answer show how to implement keyboards shortcuts ALT +S or anything like this

Comment: The thing is, its not about mplementing the hothey. That I've handled already. Now I wish to let users easily customize it via textbox. It's all described in the original post...

Comment: I've implemented similar system which allows chords (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U) in the shortcut customization. Pretty complex issue all together especially with the Oem-keys if you want to have WYSIWYG with them, eventually had to resort to very low level native api calls to get the correct character of the virtual key scancode. I am considering in writing a blog post about this but have not had the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get you started in the right direction.

First you will need the real key behind the System/ImeProcessed/DeadCharProcessed key. This can be done with extension method for easier access.

```
public static Key RealKey(this KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.System:
            return e.SystemKey;

        case Key.ImeProcessed:
            return e.ImeProcessedKey;

        case Key.DeadCharProcessed:
            return e.DeadCharProcessedKey;

        default:
            return e.Key;
    }
}
```

And then you should format your modifiers to the shortcut, not just the Key which was pressed. You can use Keyboard.ModifierKeys to get flags and for easier formatting, gather those in a list. And also you should block just a modifier key (Ctrl, Alt and Shift) from updating the hotkey.

```
private void SetHotKey(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var nonShortcuttableKeys = new[] { Key.LeftAlt, Key.RightAlt, Key.LeftCtrl, Key.RightCtrl, Key.LeftShift, Key.RightShift };
    var actualKey = e.RealKey();

    if (e.IsDown && !nonShortcuttableKeys.Contains(actualKey))
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;

        var modifiers = new List<ModifierKeys>();
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control))
        {
            modifiers.Add(ModifierKeys.Control);
        }

        if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt))
        {
            modifiers.Add(ModifierKeys.Alt);
        }

        if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift))
        {
            modifiers.Add(ModifierKeys.Shift);
        }

        tb.Text = modifiers.Count == 0
            ? string.Format("{0}", actualKey)
            : string.Format("{0} + {1}", string.Join(" + ", modifiers), actualKey);

        Hotkey = actualKey;
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working fine. I modified it slightly to suit my needs. Never realized that modifier keys can be accessed from `Keyboard` like this ;D

Answer (score 0):

**WinForms**
You can check the KeyEventArgs.Modifiers if the Ctrl is pressed or not. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.modifiers(v=vs.110).aspx

**WPF**

you can use this little snippet to check if the Control key is pressed:

```
Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)
```

If you want to use the MVVM pattern you can use the KeyBindings of the textbox (or any other control)
[Create Key binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697106/create-key-binding-in-wpf)

Comment: oops winforms answer ;-) I've edited to answer you question also on WPF

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've tried using that but it doesn't seem  to work for me. Am I doing something wrong? I updated the original post, can you take a look at it?