# Catch Alt + other key shortcut

Tags: c#, wpf, shortcut

I have to catch user's input to send a shortcut to my WPF application.
I found on internet that I have to do something like this: 
 **Catch when a key is pressed:**

```
void keyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(Modifiers.Shift))
        KeyPressed.SetShift(true);
    if (Key.Shift != e.Key && Key.LeftAlt != e.Key && ....) 
        KeyPressed.SetKey(e.Key);
}
```

where KeyPressed is a class with static boolean variables to catch if <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and another key are pressed (with <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead of <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> in the `if` clause). The second `if` is to catch a key different from <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>, Control for the shortcut. For example, for the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> we have:

1. `KeyPressed.Shift = false;`
2. `KeyPressed.Alt = true;`
3. `KeyPressed.Ctrl = false;`
4. `KeyPressed.key = Key;`

Where the last element is of type `System.Window.Input.Key`.
**Catch when a key is released:**

```
void keyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (KeyPressed.getShift()) 
        this.textField.Text += "+Shift";
    if (KeyPressed.getKeyCode())
        this.textField.Text += "+" + KeyPressed.k.toString();

    KeyPressed.SetShift(false);
}
```

and here simply I append to a textField the input received, after that I set all keys to false to catch the next shortcut correctly. 
This code works fine for all shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, **but when I press the shortcut like** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>**, it catchs only** <kbd>Alt</kbd>**, not the other key.**

How can I manage this? Is there a way to handle shortcuts in a better manner?

Comment: Better way: [InputBindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding(v=vs.110).aspx), see [this article](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/inputbindings/) for details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to get the actual key when in case of a SystemKey (<kbd>Alt</kbd> etc), you can use this helper function to get the real key behind the system key.

```
public static Key RealKey(this KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.System:
            return e.SystemKey;

        case Key.ImeProcessed:
            return e.ImeProcessedKey;

        case Key.DeadCharProcessed:
            return e.DeadCharProcessedKey;

        default:
            return e.Key;
    }
}
```

You could check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696219/how-can-i-handle-a-customizable-hotkey-setting/39703117#39703117) for more info.

Comment: how and when does this get called?

Answer (score 2):

Store the Alt-modifier state in a local variable. I'm unsure of the reasons why but this made it work for me.

```
private bool _altModifierPressed = false;

private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    _altModifierPressed = (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt));

    if (_altModifierPressed && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.V))
    {
        // code to handle Alt + V
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively, you could do something like this (no need for local variable)

```
if (((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) == ModifierKeys.Alt) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.V))
{
    // code to handle Alt + V
}
```

But I noticed that with either approach (since the enum has the Flag attribute) any combination of keys including <kbd>Alt</kbd> & <kbd>V</kbd> will work. So both execute if I for example press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `[Alt + A]` in KeyboardHook in Office VSTO, this is how it's used.

```
if (IsKeyDown(Keys.Menu) &&
    keyData == Keys.A &&

    KeyWasAlreadyPressed == false &&
    !IsKeyDown(Keys.Controlkey) &&
    !IsKeyDown(Keys.ShiftKey))
{
    //Enter your code here
}
```

**Note:**
Key.Menu denotes Alt Keys
Also condition says, Alt+A (and do not invoke when control or shift key is pressed in addition to Alt + A)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (e.Key)
{
    case Key.System:
        if (((KeyboardEventArgs)e).KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt)
        {
            if (e.SystemKey == Key.Left)
                moiveVideoPsition(-30);
            else if (e.SystemKey == Key.Right)
                moiveVideoPsition(30);
        }
        break;
```

This work well for me